# How to input data from Textfield to double in Javafx?

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

How to input data from Textfield
I need input data from TextField height to double HEIGHT.
I created button. When I click this button ,Textfield must input date to variable .
I code this block, but it doesn't work.

```
HEIGHT = 0,0 
try {
      HEIGHT = Double.parseDouble(height.getText());
     }catch(NullPointerException e) {
      System.out.println("eror");
     }
System.out.println(HEIGHT);
```

Controller.java

```
package sample;





import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;



public class Controller{
    private static Color colorOfFigure;
    private static int colorIndex, figureIndex;
    private static double  HEIGHT = 30;
    private static int WEIGHT = 50;


    @FXML
    public static TextField height;
    @FXML
    private static TextField weight;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> colorMenue;
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> figureMenue;
    @FXML
    private Canvas myCanvas;
    GraphicsContext gc;

    @FXML
    Button go;


    @FXML
    public void printFigure() {
        //COLOR MENUE
        colorMenue.setOnAction(event -> {
            colorIndex =
                    colorMenue.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        });

        //FIGURES MENUE
        figureMenue.setOnAction(event -> {
            figureIndex = figureMenue.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
        });
        printFigure(figureIndex);


        System.out.println(HEIGHT);

        }





    public Color switchColor(int i) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                colorOfFigure = Color.YELLOW;
                break;
            case 1:
                colorOfFigure = Color.GREEN;
                break;
            case 2:
                colorOfFigure = Color.BLACK;
                break;
            case 3:
                colorOfFigure = Color.RED;
                break;
            case 4:
                colorOfFigure = Color.BLUE;
                break;
        }
        return colorOfFigure;

    }

    void printFigure(int figureIndex) {
        gc = myCanvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setFill(switchColor(colorIndex));
        gc.setStroke(switchColor(colorIndex));
        switch (figureIndex) {
            case 0:
                gc.fillOval(187, 160, 100, HEIGHT);
                break;
            case 1:
                gc.fillOval(187, 160, 100, HEIGHT);
                break;
            case 2:
                gc.fillRect(187, 160, 100, 100);
                break;
            case 3:
                gc.fillPolygon(new double[]{10, 30, 10},
                        new double[]{210, 210, 240, 240,}, 4);
            case 4:
                gc.fillOval(187, 160, 100, 100);
                break;

        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void cleanCanvas() {
        gc.setFill(Color.LAVENDER);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, myCanvas.getWidth(), myCanvas.getHeight());
    }



    @FXML
    void heightAction(){
        try {
            HEIGHT = Double.parseDouble(height.getText());
        }catch(NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println("eror");

        }
    }

/*
    public void initialize() {
        try {

            height.setOnAction(event -> HEIGHT = Double.parseDouble(height.getText()));
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(height);
        }
    }
    */
}
```

My fxml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.String?>
<?import javafx.collections.FXCollections?>
<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Separator?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="700.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="26.0" layoutY="306.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#printFigure" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="print" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="figureMenue" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="52.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="            none">
      <items>
         <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Apple" />
            <String fx:value="Orange" />
            <String fx:value="Pear" />
            <String fx:value="Triq" />
         </FXCollections>
      </items>
      </ComboBox>
      <Label layoutX="34.0" layoutY="26.0" text="Choose the figure" />
      <ComboBox fx:id="colorMenue" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="135.0" prefWidth="150.0" promptText="            none">
      <items>
         <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Yellow" />
            <String fx:value="Green" />
            <String fx:value="Black" />
            <String fx:value="Red" />
            <String fx:value="Blue" />
         </FXCollections>
      </items>
   </ComboBox>
      <Label layoutX="34.0" layoutY="111.0" text="Choose the color" />
      <Canvas fx:id="myCanvas" height="400.0" layoutX="209.0" layoutY="2.0" width="499.0" />

      <Separator layoutX="206.0" layoutY="-11.0" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="365.0" prefWidth="6.0" />
      <Label layoutX="71.0" layoutY="164.0" text="figure's size" />
      <Button layoutX="26.0" layoutY="341.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#cleanCanvas" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="158.0" text="clean" textFill="#f20000" />
         <TextField fx:id="height"  onAction="#heightAction" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="HEIGHT" />
      <TextField fx:id="weight"  layoutX="115.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="WEIGHT" />
      <TextField alignment="CENTER" layoutX="30.0" layoutY="257.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="X" />
      <TextField alignment="CENTER" layoutX="118.0" layoutY="256.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="Y" />
      <Label layoutX="50.0" layoutY="235.0" text="figure's position" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: What does it so when it 'doesn't work'?

Comment: HEIGHT = 0, and in  the terminal print "eror" (try -catch)

Comment: Are you using scene builder?

Comment: what is **height.getText()** content???

Comment: @minigeek, yes . I use it

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ  height - it is the name of Textfield.

Comment: :) yes,  but it must have some string on it....#

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Yes, user will put date to height (Textfield)

Comment: @VadimMarchenko did you create method for it? if yes check my solution

Comment: `height` is [null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). [Edit] your question to include (at least) the controller code where the `height` field is declared and the FXML code where it is created.

Comment: @James_D I have added it in my answer

Comment: The problem is you made the field `static`.

Comment: @James_D thank you, dude. You are great ))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Scene Builder. Check if you have your method attached to Button id .You can do it here . give the id as button-name as you have given in code and click the method name or type in there name of method.
If you haven't created any such method then create it .

It happens we forget to link our controller and give ids in the fxml code.
here's the fix for such case :

[image]

Also All static fields in your code shouldn't be static

```
private  Color colorOfFigure;
private  int colorIndex, figureIndex;
private  double  HEIGHT = 30;
private  int WEIGHT = 50;


@FXML
public  TextField height;
@FXML
private TextField weight;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> colorMenue;
@FXML
private ComboBox<String> figureMenue;
@FXML
private Canvas myCanvas;
GraphicsContext gc;

@FXML
Button go;
```

Comment: I do it. My fxml file<TextField fx:id="height"  onAction="#heightAction" layoutX="32.0" layoutY="188.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="69.0" text="HEIGHT" > but try catch show me eror message

Comment: @VadimMarchenko can you paste your controller class code here(in question or pastebin)

Comment: yes, I have added it

Comment: @VadimMarchenko why did you add action to Textfiled. Textfield won't do anything on action .Create a new button and apply action to button not textfiled ;)

Comment: @VadimMarchenko oops seems like i am late :p

Comment: "Textfield won't do anything on action". Text fields [fire action events when the user presses enter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty).

Comment: @James_D Oh thanx. I wondered i couln't do it in my project. Thanx for info :). I forgot about eventlistner